# Bash Script to save csv to 2 files

Tags: bash, csv

My script uses an API GET request to pull data and dump to csv.  Currently my script outputs the csv using todays date.  I would also like to have it output a 2nd and identical csv.  The 2nd csv needs to always overwrite itself and would always represent the latest data pull.

My script for generating the 1st csv output is

```
 >> /mnt/d/DGD/"Market Place Scrapes"/$FILEDATE.csv
```

How do I create the second output?

Comment: `command | tee 2nd.csv  >> /mnt/d/DGD/"Market Place Scrapes/$FILEDATE.csv"`

Comment: Take a look at `man tee`.

Comment: Or `cp` the file after you download it once.